# Android permanent animation

Tags: android, animation

I want to perform simple translate animation in android 2.3. Here is what I have for now

Layout

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root_test_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/pointer_description"
        android:src="@drawable/red_dot" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/testBottomPanel"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="295dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/measure_panel" />

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/startTestSwitch"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/start_test_check"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:textOff=""
            android:textOn="" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Animation setup:

```
private void setUpView() {
            ToggleButton testSwitch = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.startTestSwitch);
            final RelativeLayout lay = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.testBottomPanel);

            final TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, 100);
            anim.setDuration(1000);
            anim.setFillAfter(true);
            anim.setAnimationListener(this);

            testSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    if(isChecked) {
                        lay.startAnimation(anim);
                    }
                    else {

                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

Listener:

```
@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
    final RelativeLayout lay = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.testBottomPanel);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)lay.getLayoutParams();
    params.topMargin += 100;
    lay.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

My problem is that when animation is completed all draws ok but my ToggleButton on layout seems to stay on its position. I mean it draws 100px below its initial position but when I tap on it is not responsive. To tap on it I need to tap 100px over the place where its draws after animation. How to translate this Toggle Button input on position where its drawning after animation?

Comment: Maybe you need to call 'invalidate()' on the button to make it redraw itself?

Answer (score 0):

You are using a view animation, which is only going to move where it is drawn, not where it can be tapped. You can switch to a property animation which will update the actual position as it moves (both where it is drawn and where it is tap-able).

Comment: What is "property animation"? and for nineoldandroid especially.

Comment: You can read about them here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html I'm not familiar with nineoldandroid, but they mention object animator on the front page being supported which is a property animation.

Comment: thank you. Discovered and tried. Unfortunately, it (in nineoldandroid on API 10) not moves view in relative layout parent to left or right. View animation moves it, but "virtually", as listed here... so only one way is to set params in the end of view animation